# In Python's stat module, when I print stat.S_IRWXU | stat.S_IRWXG | stat.S_IRWXO, why do I get 511 instead of 777?

Tags: python, chmod, stat

The octal integer to set all permissions as active is 0777. Then why do I get 511 when I print the string values of the same?

Comment: ...because `7 + (7 * 8) + (7 * (8 ** 2)) == 511`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`0777` is an octal representation.

In other word, `0777` = `7 * (8**2) + 7 * (8**1) + 7 * (8**0)`

```
>>> 0777
511
>>> 7 * (8**2) + 7 * (8**1) + 7 * (8**0)
511

>>> 0777 == 777
False
```

---

If you want to get octal representation of a number, use `oct`, `%` operator or `str.foramt` with appropriate format specifier:

```
>>> oct(511)
'0777'
>>> '%o' % 511
'777'
>>> '{:o}'.format(511)
'777'
```